# Multiple virtual host in wamp

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

I am trying to create multiple virtual host in wamp, but when i add second virtual host it shows wamp homepage.

Here is my hosts file:

```
#localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#127.0.0.1       localhost
#::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.site1.com
127.0.0.1       www.aksharen.com
::localhost
::www.site1.com
::www.aksharen.com
```

Here is my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost        
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www.site1.com/public"
    ServerName "www.site1.com"
    <Directory C:/websites/www.site1.com>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www.aksharen.com/public"
    ServerName "www.aksharen.com"
    <Directory C:/websites/www.aksharen.com>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

my first site i.e. www.site1.com is working fine.

Comment: @NishantSolanki — Why would you want virtual hosts at all if you didn't want multiple of them? The entire point of virtual hosts is to support multiple websites on a single server!

Comment: @Quentin hey sorry, I just misunderstood, I thought she wants to create virtual server on her local pc.. :P

Comment: @Vaidehi.. Hello, have you uncommented `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` this line from your `httpd.conf` file?? please refer this link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/

Comment: you can Verify virtual configuration syntax using `httpd -S`

Comment: please choose an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have made some mistakes

First

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.site1.com
127.0.0.1       www.aksharen.com
::localhost
::www.site1.com
::www.aksharen.com
```

Try changing this to

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.site1.com
127.0.0.1       www.aksharen.com
::1  localhost
::1  site1.com
::1  aksharen.com
```

Secondly may I suggest these changes to your Virtual Hosts definitions to :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www.site1.com/public"
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    <Directory "C:/websites/www.site1.com/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/www.aksharen.com/public"
    ServerName aksharen.com
    ServerAlias www.aksharen.com
    <Directory "C:/websites/www.aksharen.com/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop back addresses  ips for your virtual hosts. i.e each vhost should has its own unique loop back ip. For eaxmple, your hosts file should be something like:

```
127.0.0.100      drupal.fox
127.0.0.2      play.fox
127.0.0.3     cake241.fox
```

So your vhosts file should be something like:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.100:80>
<Directory "c:/ampps/www/drupal.fox">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName drupal.fox
ServerAlias drupal.fox
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/ampps/www/drupal.fox/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "c:/ampps/www/drupal.fox"
ErrorLog "C:/ampps/apache/logs/drupal.fox.err"
CustomLog "C:/ampps/apache/logs/drupal.fox.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course you have to create new virtual host entry with an IP equals to that found in the hosts file.

Comment: Why would you need different ip addresses when you have unique domain names?

Comment: I just feel it more clear to distinguish them using another layer, because in some local testing we may need to access the same web app from different URLs, so in this case, I could access it as drupal.fox or 127.0.0.100